# fata Exception in main and null pointer Exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, fatal-error

I have created 3 activities
In First Activity there are two buttons when I click on startNotification it starts notification
and noted down start time.when we click on notification it opens secondActivity and send noted
time.when I go to thirdActivity from there when I now go to second activity then its give error as `NullPointerException`.

**On Button Click**

> ```
>             NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
>             String MyText = "Reminder";
>             Notification mNotification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, MyText, System.currentTimeMillis() );
>             int iUniqueId = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() & 0xfffffff);
>             String MyNotificationTitle = "Medicine!";
>             String MyNotificationText  = "Don't forget to take your medicine!";
>             MyIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
>             MyIntent.putExtra("s1",System.currentTimeMillis());
> ```

```
            //PendingIntent StartIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),UNIQUE_INT_PER_CALL,MyIntent,0);

            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,iUniqueId,MyIntent,0);
            //A PendingIntent will be fired when the notification is clicked. The FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT flag cancels the pendingintent

            mNotification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), MyNotificationTitle, MyNotificationText, contentIntent);
            mNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            notificationManager.notify(0,   mNotification);
```

**Second Activity**

> ```
>     Intent i=this.getIntent();
>     if(i!=null)
>     {
>         **data=i.getStringExtra("summar");**
> ```

```
        if(data.equalsIgnoreCase("MainActivity"))
        {

            z=i.getExtras().getLong("s1");  
            int minutesZ = (int) ((z /(1000*60)) % 60);
            int minutesZ1 = (int) ((System.currentTimeMillis() /(1000*60)) % 60);
            Log.v("SecondTime",""+minutesZ);
            Log.v("CurrentTime",""+minutesZ1);
                x1=i.getExtras().getLong("s1");
            p=System.currentTimeMillis()-x1;
            int minutes = (int) ((p /(1000*60)) % 60);
            text1.setText(""+minutes);  
        }

        if(data.equalsIgnoreCase("ThirdActivity"))
        {
            //do something here
            Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this,"hiii",2000).show();
        }
    }
```

**Third Activity**

> ```
>  b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
> ```

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent i=new Intent(ThirdActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            i.putExtra("summar","ThirdActivity");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Bro, please provide logcat error.

Comment: 12-03 08:49:50.975: E/AndroidRuntime(3922): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-03 08:49:50.975: E/AndroidRuntime(3922): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-03 08:49:50.975: E/AndroidRuntime(3922):  at com.javacodegeeks.android.androidtimerexample.SecondActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.java:30)

Comment: change this two line with each other:startActivity(i);    
            i.putExtra("summar","ThirdActivity");

Comment: error comes at these lines actually data=i.getStringExtra("summar");       z=i.getExtras().getLong("s1");                               x1=i.getExtras().getLong("s1");

Comment: @ Shayan pourvatan thanks bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your third activity you are starting the intent and then putting extra into it.. Instead try:

**Third Activity**

```
 b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Intent i=new Intent(ThirdActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("summar","ThirdActivity");
        startActivity(i);

    }
});
```

And also in your second activity try to have an extra check (using **hasExtra()** option available in intent) in your condition :

```
Intent i=this.getIntent();
    if(i!=null)
    {
        if(i.hasExtra("summar"))        //---Might be useful if the intent doesn't have that extra
             data=i.getStringExtra("summar");

    if(data.equalsIgnoreCase("MainActivity"))
    {

        z=i.getExtras().getLong("s1");  
        int minutesZ = (int) ((z /(1000*60)) % 60);
        int minutesZ1 = (int) ((System.currentTimeMillis() /(1000*60)) % 60);
        Log.v("SecondTime",""+minutesZ);
        Log.v("CurrentTime",""+minutesZ1);
            x1=i.getExtras().getLong("s1");
        p=System.currentTimeMillis()-x1;
        int minutes = (int) ((p /(1000*60)) % 60);
        text1.setText(""+minutes);  
    }

    if(data.equalsIgnoreCase("ThirdActivity"))
    {
        //do something here
        Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this,"hiii",2000).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: its work for secondActivity fine..but now it gives error when i Click on notification.its give error at if(data.equalsIgnoreCase("MainActivity")) if you know bro please suggest same error occure

Comment: @Yash you are not passing any extra with tag "data" on notification click.. So, it is throwing error..